# input validation for choosing an item with a char, getting errors with cin.fail

Tags: c++, validation, input, char, cin

cin is really difficult for me to understand with c++.

I want to choose an item on the menu but I want it to be clean, however I am running into issues with cin.fail.

I realize cin.fail checks the datatype so I should be clear when it comes to other data types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int number;//   define an integer variable called number
float cost;//   a floating point variable called cost,
char beverage;//    and a character variable called beverage
bool validBeverage;

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

do
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Hot Beverage Menu" << endl << endl;
    cout << "A: Coffee         $1.00" << endl;
    cout << "B: Tea            $ .75" << endl;
    cout << "C: Hot Chocolate  $1.25" << endl;
    cout << "D: Cappuccino     $2.50" << endl <<endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the beverage A,B,C, or D you desire" << endl;
    cout << "Enter E to exit the program" << endl << endl;

    do
    {
        cin >> beverage;// Fill in the code to read in beverage
        if (cin.fail)
        {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid value." <<  endl 

<< "Please enter the letter corresponding to the menu." << endl;
        }
    } while (cin.fail);


    switch(beverage)
    {
        case 'a':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'A':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'b':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'B':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'c':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'C':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'd':  validBeverage = true;
        case 'D':  validBeverage = true;
               break;
        default:   validBeverage = false;
    }// end switch beverage

    if (validBeverage == true)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "How many cups would you like?" << endl;
            // Fill in the code to read in number
            cin >> number;
            if (cin.fail() || number <= 0)
            {

cout << "You have entered an invalid value." << endl <<

"Please enter an integer greater than 0." << endl;`enter code here`
            }
        } while (cin.fail() || number <= 0);
    }

    switch (beverage)// Fill in the code to begin a switch 

statement that is controlled by beverage
    {
        case 'a': (float)cost = number * 1.0;
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'A': (float)cost = number * 1.0;
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'b': (float)cost = number * 0.75;// Fill in the 

code to give the case for tea ( $0.75 a cup)
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'B': (float) cost = number * 0.75;// Fill in the 

code to give the case for hot chocolate ($1.25 a cup)
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'c': (float)cost = number * 1.25;
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'C': (float)cost = number * 1.25;
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'd': (float)cost = number * 2.50;// Fill in the 

code to give the case for cappuccino ($2.50 a cup)      
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'D': (float)cost = number * 2.50;// Fill in the 

code to give the case for cappuccino ($2.50 a cup)      
            cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
            break;
        case 'e': 
            cout << "Please come again." << endl;
            break;
        case 'E':
            cout << " Please come again." << endl;
            break;
        default:cout << "Invalid Selection."; // Fill in the 

code to write a message indicating an invalid selection.
            cout << " Try again please" << endl;
    }

}while (beverage != 'e' || beverage != 'E'); // Fill in the code to 

finish the do-while statement with the condition that beverage does not 

equal E or e.

// Fill in the appropriate return statement
return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try using: `if(!cin)` which checks for data type on input.